# com.ibm.ws.management.webserver.ServerNotAvailableException: No Connection

Tags: websphere

Installed was with dmgr and appserver profile on node 1

then installed Appserver with ihs on node 2

now Iam trying to connect ihs on node2 to dmgr on node1 by generating and propagating plugins

when i was created webserver in console  webserver is formed at dmgr level but it was not formed at ihs level.

Please reply me on this problem